# Can I select two columns into hashsets in a single query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a table that looks like this,
I want to get hashsets of Column 1 and Column 2 respectively.

| Id | Type | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | provider 1 |
| 2 | motor | provider 2 |
| 3 | bike | provider 2 |

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
var types = _context.MyEntities
    .Select(m => m.Type)
    .ToHashSet();

var providers = _context.MyEntities
    .Select(m => m.Provider)
    .ToHashSet();
```

How can I combine it into a single query?
Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: check my answer if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using an anonymous type that combines the two properties in the select delegate.

```
var results = _context.MyEntities.Select(m => new { m.Type, m.Provider }).ToHashSet();
```

PS: The `Select` starts with a capital letter.